# Update table contents after model change

Tags: tornadofx

I'm testing tornadofx framework (copy pasting examples mostly), I have strange issue that table contents are not updated after edit. I see that contents of

```
val persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Person>()
val selectedPerson = PersonModel()
```

are changing, but view is not. As I've taken example from tornadofx github, I'm very confused.

Here are classes

```
class Person(id: Int, name: String) {
    var id by property(id)
    fun idProperty() = getProperty(Person::id)

    var name by property(name)
    fun nameProperty() = getProperty(Person::name)

}

class PersonModel : ItemViewModel<Person>() {
    val id = bind { item?.idProperty() }
    val name = bind { item?.nameProperty() }
}

class PersonController : Controller() {
    val persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Person>()
    val selectedPerson = PersonModel()

    init {
        // Add some test persons for the demo
        persons.add(Person(42, "John Doe"))
        persons.add(Person(43, "Jane Doe"))
    }
}

class MainWindow : View("FX Test") {

    private val controller: PersonController by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {

        center = tableview(controller.persons) {

            column("ID", Person::id)
            column("Name", Person::name)
            bindSelected(controller.selectedPerson)

            contextmenu {
                item("Edit", KeyCombination.keyCombination("F3")).action {

                    dialog("Client editor") {

                        field("Name") {
                            textfield(controller.selectedPerson.name)
                        }

                        buttonbar {
                            button("Save") {
                                setOnAction {
                                    controller.selectedPerson.commit()
                                    close()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According documentation, after controller commit, view is updated automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the table columns to the getters instead of the observable properties, so they have no way of knowing when the data changes. Simply point the column builders to the properties instead:

```
column("ID", Person::idProperty)
column("Name", Person::nameProperty)
```